# How to know the line width of enumeration in two column document prior to entering the enumeration?

Tags: equations, best-practices, lengths

[image]

I want to populate the following lengths just **once prior to entering the enumeration** (or perhaps prior to entering the `document` environment) to free me from worrying whether or not the initialization has been invoked.

```
\newlength\EWD
\newlength\HWD
\newlength\HHWD
```

The initialization routine is given as follows,

```
\def\Init{%
    \settowidth{\EWD}{${}={}$}%
    \setlength{\HWD}{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\EWD\relax}%
    \setlength{\HHWD}{0.5\HWD}}
```

And the following is my real scenario.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength\EWD
\newlength\HWD
\newlength\HHWD

\def\Init{%
    \settowidth{\EWD}{${}={}$}%
    \setlength{\HWD}{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\EWD\relax}%
    \setlength{\HHWD}{0.5\HWD}}

\def\TopLHS#1{\mathrlap{#1}\rule{\HWD}{0pt}}
\def\MiddleLHS#1{\rule{\HHWD}{0pt}\mathclap{#1}\rule{\HHWD}{0pt}}
\def\BottomLHS#1{\rule{\HWD}{0pt}\mathllap{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\Init
$\!
\begin{aligned}[t]  
\TopLHS{\framebox[3cm]{Top LHS}}\\
\MiddleLHS{\framebox[3cm]{Middle LHS}}\\
\BottomLHS{\framebox[3cm]{Bottom LHS}}
    &= \begin{multlined}[t][\HWD]
            \framebox[3cm]{Top RHS 1}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Middle RHS 1}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Bottom RHS 1}
        \end{multlined}\\
    &= \begin{multlined}[t][\HWD]
            \framebox[3cm]{Top RHS 2}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Middle RHS 2}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Bottom RHS 2}
        \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: I don't understand: you want to avoid having to write `\Init` after `\item`? Then add `\Init` to the code of `\item`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. I don't want to write `\Init` for the first `\item` every time I start a new `enumerate`. In other words, I want to inject checking statement like `\ifinitdefined` plus invoking `\Init` if it is undefined to the first occurrence of `item` for each `enumerate` invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of adding `\Init` as the first duty of `\item`; other places don't guarantee that the parameters are correctly evaluated

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\item\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\Init\item}%
}



\newlength\EWD
\newlength\HWD
\newlength\HHWD

\def\Init{%
    \settowidth{\EWD}{${}={}$}%
    \setlength{\HWD}{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\EWD\relax}%
    \setlength{\HHWD}{0.5\HWD}}

\def\TopLHS#1{\mathrlap{#1}\rule{\HWD}{0pt}}
\def\MiddleLHS#1{\rule{\HHWD}{0pt}\mathclap{#1}\rule{\HHWD}{0pt}}
\def\BottomLHS#1{\rule{\HWD}{0pt}\mathllap{#1}}

\def\showInit{\texttt{EWD=\the\EWD; HWD=\the\HWD; HHWD=\the\HHWD}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
$\!
\begin{aligned}[t]  
\TopLHS{\framebox[3cm]{Top LHS}}\\
\MiddleLHS{\framebox[3cm]{Middle LHS}}\\
\BottomLHS{\framebox[3cm]{Bottom LHS}}
    &= \begin{multlined}[t][\HWD]
            \framebox[3cm]{Top RHS 1}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Middle RHS 1}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Bottom RHS 1}
        \end{multlined}\\
    &= \begin{multlined}[t][\HWD]
            \framebox[3cm]{Top RHS 2}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Middle RHS 2}\\
            \framebox[3cm]{Bottom RHS 2}
        \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
$
\item\showInit
  \begin{itemize}
  \item\showInit
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\showItem` macro is just to show the values of the parameters, which are different in the inner `itemize` as it should be.

Comment: Should it be better to do checking before entering the first item?

Comment: @Bugbusters I stand corrected: not all the parameters are computed when `before` is evaluated. So there's not much hope other than adding `\Init` to `\item`, which was my original idea.